# How to override default-filters args at route level in spring cloud gateway?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - name: AuthFilter
          args:
            enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: route
          uri: "${SERVICE1:http://localhost:8080}"
          predicates:
            - Path=/route-1/**
          filters:
            - name: AuthFilter
              args:
                enabled: false
```

How to override the default config args as shown above? Currently the route level args are ignored. The use case is I want to enable a filter by default but skip only for some specific routes.